# Multiple Raphael Clocks on one page, not passing hours/minutes

Tags: javascript, arrays, raphael, clock

Working through a teaching example for very crisp Raphael-library world clocks and I'm missing something somewhere: Clocks display with `serverHours` and `serverMinutes` set as static values. Code below does not display. Greatly appreciate 2nd (or more) set of eyes catching what I'm missing. Thanks!

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
       <title>Multiple Raphael Clocks on Same Page</title>
       <meta name="description" content="">
       <meta name="keywords" content="">
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/raphael-min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript"  
   function updateClock()
   {
     var currentTime = new Date();
     var currentHours = currentTime.getHours ( );
     var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes ( );
   currentHours = ( currentHours < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentHours;
   currentMinutes = ( currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentMinutes;
   </script>

   <body onload="updateClock();">

            <div id="clock" style="padding:0px;"></div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   cities = [['Houston',-6],['Charleston',-5],['London',0],['Malta',1],['Bucharest',2],['Brisbane',10],['San Diego',-9]];
   serverHours = currentHours;
   serverMinutes = currentMinutes;
   clock24 = false;
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function Clock( paper, x, y, offH, offM, title, clock24 )
   {
       this.paper = paper;
       this.centerX = x;
       this.centerY = y;
       this.offsetHour = offH;
       this.offsetMinute = offM;
       this.title = title;
       this.radius = 14;
       this.circle;
       this.arrowHour;
       this.arrowMinute;
       this.clock24 = clock24;
       this.Clock = function()
       {
           this.circle = this.paper.circle(this.centerX, this.centerY, this.radius);
           this.circle.attr({"fill": "#fff", "stroke": "#fff"});
           this.arrowHour = this.paper.path(
               "M" + this.centerX + " " + (this.centerY - this.radius + 6) + " "
               + "L" + this.centerX + " " + this.centerY
               );
           this.arrowHour.attr({"stroke": "#fff", "stroke-width": "2"});
           this.arrowMinute = this.paper.path(
               "M" + this.centerX + " " + (this.centerY - this.radius + 2) + " "
               + "L" + this.centerX + " " + this.centerY
               );
           this.arrowMinute.attr({"stroke": "#fff", "stroke-width": "2"});
           var label = this.paper.text(this.centerX, (this.centerY + this.radius + 10), title);
           label.attr({"fill" : "#666", "font-size" : "9"});
       }
       this.showTime = function()
       {
           var date = new Date();
           var hours = date.getHours() + this.offsetHour;
           if (hours > 24) hours -= 24;
           if (hours < 0) hours += 24;
    var dHours = hours;
    var dPostfix = "";
           var color = (13 - Math.ceil(13.0/144.0 * Math.pow(Math.abs(hours-12), 2))).toString(16);
           var minutes = date.getMinutes() + this.offsetMinute;
           this.arrowMinute.rotate(minutes*6, this.centerX, this.centerY);

           if (hours > 12) hours -= 12;
    if (!this.clock24)
    {
        dPostfix = (dHours >= 12 ? " PM" : " AM");
        dHours = hours;
    }
           this.arrowHour.rotate((parseFloat(hours)+parseFloat(minutes)/60)*30, this.centerX, this.centerY);
    if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
           this.circle.attr({"fill": "#"+color+color+color, "stroke": "#"+color+color+color, "title": "" + dHours+":"+minutes+dPostfix});
       }
       this.Clock();
   }
   var clock = new Array();
   function refreshTime()
   {
       if (clock)
       {
           for (var i = 0; i < clock.length; i++)
           {
               clock[i].showTime();
           }
       }
   }
   var paper = Raphael("clock", 330, 60);
   var date = new Date();
   var offsetHours = serverHours - date.getHours();
   var offsetMinutes = serverMinutes - date.getMinutes();
   var x = 20;
   var y = 21;
   for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++)
   {
    clock.push(new Clock(paper, x, y, offsetHours + cities[i][1], offsetMinutes, cities[i][0], clock24));
    x += 55;
   }
   refreshTime();
   setInterval( "refreshTime()", 30000 );
   </script>
   </body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many errors in your JavaScript. Open your page in Google Chrome, press F12, switch to "Console" tab and see all errors marked with red color.

Also you're using #fff fill/stroke color everywhere which is white so it becomes invisible on white background.

Also you're trying to globally use variable "currentHours" etc. which definition is enclosed in function so it becomes not global but local. Move it to a global scope (above all functions).

Comment: Thanks oyatek! Got pulled away on another task. This got lost in the shuffle. Will try out your suggestions.

Comment: @systhink 5 years later? really? :)